# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'openSnackBar')

Tags: angular, angular-material

Yesterday I've came across this problem and I can't handle this since.

I have service that fires http get request. In case of error I want to display `MatSnackBar`. But I've got many of those services so I decided to create service for snackbar. Then I just inject my `snackbarService` and display message. But I don't know why, it doesn't work.

**HttpService**

```js
this._http.get<IObjectNumber[]>(this.formatUrl()).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.formatData(data, tempSeries, tempLabels);
                this.createChart(tempSeries, tempLabels);
                this.updateChart();
            },
            (err) => this.catchError(err)
        );

catchError(err): void {
    this._sbService.openSnackBar('Error', 'Close');
}
```

**snackBarService**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SnackBarService {
    constructor(private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

    openSnackBar(message: string, action: string): void {
        this._snackBar.open(message, action, {
            duration: 2000,
            panelClass: ['snackbar'],
        });
    }
}
```

Error points the catchError method in `HttpService`.
I made sure that I import `MatSnackBarModule` in my module.

Could you give me a hand with this?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what type of errors  you are expecting, because your code enters to error block for 500 and 400 response code.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `catchError` method is not an instance method you need to bind `this` to access any instance variables. Just change your code:

```
this.catchError(err)
```

to

```
this.catchError(err).bind(this)
```

Or, you can make `catchError` an instance method by simply taking it out side of the method from where you are calling the API.